# Does a PCB circuit work without soldering the paste?

Tags: solder-paste

So the case is simple. I have to tune a Pi antenna matching network (a simple LC filter). That means I have to place and unplace a couple of pasives back and forth until I find out the right pair of values. Even if I do that operation with hot air gun, I am afraid I can damage the pad due to solder and desolder the component too many times.

I have been wondering if I can test the LC filter without heating the components, that is, I just place the L and C on the pads, as they are 0402, they stick to the pads and I can manipulate the board carefully. They do not fall unless you shake the board, what allows me to test it quickly and swap the components again without using heat.

I realized the paste is sill conductive before being heated but I don't know if the qualities of my LC network will be affected by this and so my tests will be really giving reliable data or not.

Have you people done this before?
Many thanks
Mario

Comment: No. Just no. Contact resistance will be in the 10 to 10000 Ohm range at best, not to mention HF effects of bad solder joints, let alone no-solder joints.

Comment: Why not do things properly and design the network first?

Comment: Holding the components down against the bare pads would be a better approximation!

Comment: I see. Then I will solder the components as carefully as posible.

Comment: Leon Heller, the values of the network really depends on the final real PCB and its components. The only way to find out the right values is using a Network Analyzer and try some values to tune the antenna.

Comment: Have you thought about using a *trim capacitor*?

Comment: You could try a paste or weak adhesive *designed* for high conductivity instead, and then use solder afterward. [Example.](http://www.mgchemicals.com/products/greases-and-lubricants/conductive-greases/carbon-conductive-assembly-paste-847/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.  Solder paste is microscopic balls of solder suspended in flux.  Some fluxes are outright insulators, but none of them have sufficiently low resistivity to make a good connection.  You can't count on the solder balls touching, since many of them won't.

All around this is a bad idea.

Comment: Olin, thanks for your answer. I had test the connectivity with the multimeter and it did actually connect but I supposed I can't rely on it, based on your explanation